# How to add message to datatables pagination line

Tags: jquery, datatables, pagination

Using jQuery Datatables I would like to add a message to the same line as the pagination or page selector line.

Using the code below I can add a custom message to the top, but is there anyway to move the custom message to the bottom and have it float to the right of the Datatables page selector? I think I need to add bottom somehow, somewhere, but the DataTables documentation is not very helpful.

```
        $("#tbl_usersearch").dataTable({
            searching: false, info: false, lengthChange: false, "dom": '<"add_message">frtip',
        });
        var add_html =
         '<div id="div_message" class="float_right ">' +
            '<img id="img_success" class="" src="/Content/Icons/success.png" style="height:18px;" />' +
            '<img id="img_warning" class="" src="/Content/Icons/warning.png" style="height:18px;" />' +
            '<span id="lbl_message">Message</span>' +
        '</div>';

        $("div.add_message").html(add_html);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option so that `<"add_message">` is after `t` (`t`able), for example:

```
"dom": 'frti<"add_message">p'
```

Also apply CSS rules to `add_message` class if necessary.

See [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option for more information.

Comment: That worked and ?somehow? your response has helped me understand the documentation a little better. The DataTables doc provides examples but they do not discuss how they actually work. I see now that whatever I insert needs to either precede or follow the f for filter, t for table, etc.